# sudo commands takes long time

Tags: linux, root

Running any command with sudo takes long time. Steps:

1. Login to the server with regular user
   `ssh my_user@my.server.com`
2. `$ sudo su`
   here it takes some minutes

Why does it take so long?

Not sure if it has something to do, but when I run `users`, I get the following:

```
$ users
my_user root root
```

Why do I have 2 root users? They are not defined in passwd:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd|grep root
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
$ id
uid=1001(my_user) gid=100(users) groups=100(users) # -> run as my_user
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)   # -> run as root
```

I know it's useless but If I ssh as root user to the machine and I run `sudo su` it also behaves the same way.

Comment: The only explicit question is "why do I have 2 root users?". Is "how to reduce the delay?" also your question? Maybe even the main one?

Comment: Might be worth checking the logs: run `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` then try the offending sudo command on another terminal to see whether anything useful is being logged

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski both are valid questions and might be correlated to each other

Comment: I don't have that log, but I found in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` that the operation `CRED_REFR` has `hostname=? addr=?` and later on the operation `USER_START` has already the proper value in hostname.

Comment: They are valid, they may be correlated. My point is: what are you asking? Suppose someone answers the explicit question and doesn't solve the problem of delay *at all* (because *maybe* they are not that correlated). Will it be enough? I don't want to claim I know better what you are asking (this would be rude), therefore I want to be sure.